# Java 6 Sort array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have to design a interface method which accepts an primitive [] array and perform a sort and return back an primitive [] array for a LOW LATENCY (high performance) requirement and will be called by many threads at the same time

Is sorted set or int[] better to use for this purpose which requires very high performance?

Would appreciate any reply thanks

Comment: "and will be called by many threads at the same time" makes no difference in your example. Unless you meant: the method should use many threads to improve performance.

Comment: Also: what is wrong with `Arrays.sort(yourArrayOfInts);`?

Comment: What numbers are you expecting? How are they distributed?

Comment: Basically this method will be called by a calculation engine.. This method might be called like say a 2 million times per second and I am ure Array.Sort is not efficient. The max size can be 100 elements in this array

Comment: What breeds the confidence that Array.Sort is not efficient? Do you just not trust the years of development and expertise that went into that library or do you have actual numbers to back up your statement?

Comment: How are they distributed? that is the key. if YOUR REALLY SURE that they will be all between x and y then someone can give you a better answer. also what is an interface method? do you mean a utility method?

Answer (score 4):

> This method might be called like say a 2 million times per second and I am sure Array.Sort is not efficient for this. The max size can be 100 elements in this array

A quick micro benchmark shows that `Arrays.sort` can sort an `int[]` array of 100 `int`s in approx. 1.3 microseconds* on a standard desktop machine (i7), using one core.

So you can call it about 800,000 times per second (still assuming you only use 1 core). So **if you have 4 processors or more you should be able to run 2 million sort operations per second**.

Note: if your arrays have a typical characteristic (say many duplicates or mostly sorted or numbers all in a fairly narrow range) you might be able to find a better suited algo but for a general use case I am pretty sure the JDK algo is quite robust and efficient.

---

*Results of the micro-benchmark (done with jmh):

```
Run result "sort": 1341.298 ±(95%) 11.701 ±(99%) 19.406 nsec/op
Run statistics "sort": min = 1331.329, avg = 1341.298, max = 1352.831, stdev = 9.425
Run confidence intervals "sort": 95% [1329.597, 1352.999], 99% [1321.892, 1360.704]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
String[] fruits = new String[] {"Pineapple","Apple", "Orange", "Banana"}; 

    Arrays.sort(fruits);

    int i=0;
    for(String temp: fruits){
        System.out.println("fruits " + ++i + " : " + temp);
}
```

Or this...

```
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<String>();

    fruits.add("Pineapple");
    fruits.add("Apple");
    fruits.add("Orange");
    fruits.add("Banana");

    Collections.sort(fruits);

    int i=0;
    for(String temp: fruits){
        System.out.println("fruits " + ++i + " : " + temp);
}
```

Read this... [QuickSort](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/quicksorting-3-way-and-dual-pivot.html)

Comment: Basically this method will be called by a calculation engine.. This method might be called like say a 2 million times per second and I am sure Array.Sort is not efficient for this. The max size can be 100 elements in this array